# Removing SKAction (that is playing an MP3) instantly while waitforCompletion is YES

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skaction

Im trying to remove a repeated playing MP3 when two nodes collide.

```
SKAction* gameBeat = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"gameBeat.mp3" waitForCompletion:YES];
SKAction* gameBeatLoop = [SKAction repeatActionForever: gameBeat];
[self runAction:gameBeatLoop withKey:@"gameBeatzz"];
```

then later down in my code where I have collision working
I put :

```
[self removeActionForKey:@"gameBeatzz"];
```

but it waits until the MP3 is done playing, which I do not want.

If I change waitForCompletion to NO, the APP just gets messed up and won't do anything.

How would I go about removing the Mp3 instantly instead of waiting for the MP3 file to finish

Comment: Can you use AVAudioPlayer instead?

Comment: Or an actual audio engine like ObjectAL. I don't think what you want to do can be done with Sprite Kit's minimalistic audio playback functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **normal** that if you set your `waitForCompletion` bool to NO the app doesn't do anything. It is because the action is considered to have completed **immediately**.

The action for `playSoundFileNamed` is not *reversible* and makes a *final change* to the scene when removed, it continues to the end...
Some `SKAction` are completely removed from node when you perform the `removeAction` method, but some continues to work.

The `playSoundFileNamed` was created to perform short sounds and not a **background** sound.

I recommend to use the `AVAudioPlayer` that allows you bigger control on music.